# What kind of trouble will it cause to run an older kernel?

Tags: centos6, openvz, linux-kernel, containers, ubuntu-16.04

I started to try to get acquainted with openvz.

Following the instructions [here](https://openvz.org/Quick_installation) I installed my first ever openvz server on centos 6.

The first container I spawned was based on the `ubuntu-16.04-x86_64` template.

After creation I entered it and ran:

```
# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

The upgrade seem successful, but throws the following warning:

[image]

Which I guess is natural as Ubuntu 16.04 normally runs version 4.4 of the kernel but the container will have to make do with the version used by centos 6, which is 2.6.

What sort of trouble could one expect to run into using such a relatively outdated kernel?

Comment: There's a very lengthy list of reasons why nobody should use OpenVZ, and this is but one of them. I don't know what you intend to accomplish, but I would recommend that you find another way to do it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, any chance you could direct me to such a list?

Comment: I imagine the problem is the same with all types of containers when the host/container image start to diverge to much, it should not only be a openvz question.